# Neo4J: What is the CQL for expanding node with child relationships

Tags: neo4j

I've been learning Neo4j CQL and using Neo4j Browser(version 3.0.5)

Neo4j Browser provides the function for expanding the child relationships(double click also works), but not provides the expanding CQL.

When generating just A node in the first

```
match (n:Person{name:"xx"}) return n
```

double click works the same with the CQL

```
match p=((n:Person{name:"xx"})-[]-()) return n
```

But not the same when generating several nodes (tried the cql like)

```
match p=(n:Person{name:"xx"})-[]-()-[]-(m:Person) return p
```

What confuses me is that is there A fixed style for CQL to this function?
Any suggestions?
if not fixed, cql for 2 or 3 nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to read up on [variable-length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength) in Cypher patterns, and in general reading through the entire Cypher manual ought to be helpful.

An example of usage for getting paths of length 2-3 from a starting node, regardless of relationship type or direction:

```
MATCH p = (:Person{name:"xx"})-[*2..3]-()
RETURN p
```